# C++ raw pointers using this for operator overload results in segmentation fault when freeing memory

Tags: c++, pointers, operator-overloading

I am trying to build a Tree of operations for a Tensor application in c++.
When I write `c = a + b` I would like `c` to have as children two pointers `a` and `b`.
I pass the "this" of `a` to the constructor of `c` and then I free the memory in the destructor.

```c++
template<typename T>
struct ObjectPointers {
    const ObjectPointers<T> *left;
    const ObjectPointers<T> *right;
    vector<T> data;

    // initialize left and right in constructor
    ObjectPointers(std::initializer_list<T> list) : data(list) {
        left = nullptr;
        right = nullptr;
    }

    ~ObjectPointers(){
        // somewhere around here the error happens
        if(left != nullptr)
            delete left;
        if(right != nullptr)
            delete right;
    }

    ObjectPointers(const ObjectPointers<T> *left, const ObjectPointers<T> *right) : left(left), right(right) {}

    //overload +
    ObjectPointers operator+(const ObjectPointers &other) const {
        // I create a new object with the left and right of the current object
        return ObjectPointers<T>(this, &other);
    }
};

int main() {
    ObjectPointers<int> a = {1, 2, 3};
    ObjectPointers<int> b = {4, 5, 6};
    ObjectPointers<int> c = a + b;

    return 0;
}
```

The way I understand the code that I wrote is as follows:
Object `c` is created and points to `a` and `b`.

`c` goes out of scope => It calls the destructor => `delete a` => destructor of `a` is called => Nothing happens

=> `delete b` => Destructor of `b` is called => Nothing happens => Destructor of `c` is done

Where I wrote "Nothing happens" in reality a segmentation fault happens and I do not understand why.

I also tried using `smart_pointers` but that did not really help. I used `std::unique_ptr<>`.

Comment: I am a beginner in C++, so forgive me for not knowing how to phrase the question correctly. I want to understand why the code does not work and what should I do to fix it. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You copy the pointers in the constructor then each copy is deleted in the destructors so that's double deletion.

Comment: Can I avoid copying the pointers in the constructor to make the code work?

Comment: You can avoid deleting pointers, because your objects are on the stack and not allocated with `new`  you shouldn't delete them. Or you could allocate with `std::make_shared` then you don't have to delete them explicitly because it's automatic.

Comment: Ok, you are right that makes sense. That would mean that I should have no destructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### What's the problem?

This is not a sound design, because it does not respect the usual properties of +,  for example that `(x+y)+z` is the same than `x+(y+z)`.

If you nevertheless want to make it work,  you'd need to extract the `operator+` of the class, and use an overload of the binary `operator+`.

In addition, you have to work properly with destruction, and avoid destroying an object which is still used in some of the `ObjectPointers`.  For this you should use `shared_ptr` and not `unique_ptr`.

(The advantage is that when an object gets destroyed, the shared pointer is kept alive as long as another object still uses the pointer.  Your current design with raw pointers might lead multiple `ObjectPointers` use the same pointer, and the first `ObjectPointers` that gets deleted, deletes the pointer, and the others then refer to dangling pointers.  This is undefined behavior and very bad)

### How to solve it?

The code would look somewhat like this (caution,  I didn't analyse if it further for other issues):

```
template<typename T>
struct ObjectPointers {
    const std::shared_ptr<ObjectPointers<T>> left;
    const std::shared_ptr<ObjectPointers<T>> right;
    std::vector<T> data;

    // initialize left and right in constructor
    ObjectPointers(std::initializer_list<T> list) : data(list) {
    }

    ObjectPointers(const ObjectPointers &c) = default;
    ~ObjectPointers(){  // no need,  shared ptr take care
     }

    ObjectPointers(std::shared_ptr<ObjectPointers<T>> left, std::shared_ptr<ObjectPointers<T>> right) : left(left), right(right) {}

};
```

And:

```
//overload +
template <class T>
ObjectPointers<T> operator+ (ObjectPointers<T> a, ObjectPointers<T> b)  {
     // I create a new object with the left and right of the current object
     return ObjectPointers<T>(std::make_shared<ObjectPointers<T>>(a), std::make_shared<ObjectPointers<T>>(b));
}
```

Here an **[online demo](https://ideone.com/bbdHIA)**, including printing of the resulting structure.

Comment: I understand that the usual properties of + will not be respected, I think I am ok with that.
The issue with the code was that I was destroying objects `a` and `b` before they went out of scope?

Comment: How would I move the binary `operator+` outside the class? Does that mean using a friend function?

Comment: @nickk2002 I've edited to explain more.  But again, I'd advise against the misuse of operator+